# org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput() in oozie

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, mapper, reducers

I am trying to use **MultipleOutputs** for changing output filename in reducer. I am using oozie workflow to run mapreduce job.

I am not able to find ways to add below property in oozie workflow -

```
MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(job, "text", TextOutputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class);
```

As it is oozie mapreduce action, I don't have driver class to put above code.

Comment: I know it's not a directly helpful answer, but I always found running MR jobs through Oozie to be a pain. I would always run the MR job through Oozie as you'd run a normal JAR in Oozie. That way you can use a Driver class.

Comment: @CharitraKocheri I have added a possible solution. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the source code for the method.
From `hadoop core 1.2.1` jar

```
/*     */   public static void addNamedOutput(Job job, String namedOutput, Class<? extends OutputFormat> outputFormatClass, Class<?> keyClass, Class<?> valueClass)
/*     */   {
/* 248 */     checkNamedOutputName(job, namedOutput, true);
/* 249 */     Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();
/* 250 */     conf.set("mapreduce.multipleoutputs", conf.get("mapreduce.multipleoutputs", "") + " " + namedOutput);
/*     */     
/* 252 */     conf.setClass("mapreduce.multipleoutputs.namedOutput." + namedOutput + ".format", outputFormatClass, OutputFormat.class);
/*     */     
/* 254 */     conf.setClass("mapreduce.multipleoutputs.namedOutput." + namedOutput + ".key", keyClass, Object.class);
/* 255 */     conf.setClass("mapreduce.multipleoutputs.namedOutput." + namedOutput + ".value", valueClass, Object.class);
/*     */   }
```

So, it points towards setting `"mapreduce.multipleoutputs"` again with space separated `namedOutput` and setting format, key and value classes using below variables.

```
"mapreduce.multipleoutputs.namedOutput." + namedOutput + ".format"
"mapreduce.multipleoutputs.namedOutput." + namedOutput + ".key"
"mapreduce.multipleoutputs.namedOutput." + namedOutput + ".value"
```

Hope it helps.